# ORDER BY depending on two date columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using Postgresql 10 and trying to order my select query to get on top the smaller date between two date columns I have.

Here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2df2b/24/0)

Ordered result would be something like this:

```
+----+--------------+--------------+
| id | column1_date | column2_date |
+----+--------------+--------------+
| 1  | 2018-05-07   | null         |
+----+--------------+--------------+
| 3  | null         | 2018-05-28   |
+----+--------------+--------------+
| 2  | 2018-06-28   | 2018-06-30   |
+----+--------------+--------------+
| 4  | null         | 2018-07-12   |
+----+--------------+--------------+
```

I've tried to do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Test
    ORDER BY 
      CASE WHEN column1_date is null AND column2_date is not null
          THEN column2_date END ASC, column1_date ASC,

      CASE WHEN column1_date is not null AND column2_date is null
          THEN column1_date END ASC, column2_date ASC,

      CASE WHEN column1_date is not null AND column2_date is not null AND column1_date < column2_date
          THEN column1_date END ASC, column2_date ASC,

      CASE WHEN column1_date is not null AND column2_date is not null AND column1_date > column2_date
          THEN column2_date END ASC, column1_date ASC
```

But this wasn't a success.
What am I missing ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use

```
ORDER BY least(coalesce(column1_date, DATE 'infinity'),
               coalesce(column2_date, DATE 'infinity'))
```

That will always use the smaller of the two.

If both columns are NULL, the row will be sorted last.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inner subquery:

```
select 
  t.id, t.column1_date, t.column2_date
from (
  select 
    id, 
    column1_date, 
    column2_date,
    CASE 
      WHEN column1_date is null then column2_date
      WHEN column2_date is null then column1_date
      WHEN column1_date < column2_date THEN column1_date
      ELSE column2_date
    END AS min_date
  from Test) as t
order by t.min_date;
```